# Является ли экшен обновления одного из нескольких атрибутов отхождением от REST в Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Есть задача - передвинуть заказ в состояние `complete`. Это делается с помощью библиотеки `aasm_state`. Способ, которым я это сделаю не так важен (приложение учебное), важно узнать какой из них предпочтительнее.

#### 1

```
  #orders_controller.rb
  def update
    @order.update(order_params)
  end

  #index.html.erb
  <%= button_to 'Выполнен', order, method: PATCH, aasm_state: 'complete' %>
```

#### 2

```
  #orders_controller.rb
  def complete
    @order.complete!
  end

  #index.html.erb
  <%= button_to 'Выполнен', complete_order_path(order) %>
```

В первом случае - есть экшен `update`, который принимает статус из параметров. Параметры запроса указаны на фронтенде внутри формы с кнопкой.

Минусы:

- Состояние заказа вынесено в открытую часть приложения - на фронтенд. Я могу открыть инспектор, вбить в поле `aasm_state` другое значение и отправить запрос.

Во втором случае - есть экшен `complete`, который ничего не принимает из параметров. Он сам знает в какое состояние нужно передвинуть заказ.

Тут есть минус:

- если заказ в приложении мог бы еще и редактироваться, в контроллере было бы 2 похожих метода(`update` vs `update, complete`). Не соблюдается `DRY`.
- хорошо ли хранить состояние в контроллере (имею в виду, что контроллер сам знает в какой статус передвинуть заказ)?

#### Собственно, вопросы

- Какие еще важные минусы\преимущества есть у обоих способов?
- Насколько я правильно понял Rails, создание экшенов, которые не являются одним из `[new create show index edit update destroy]` - это отхождение от REST. Так ли это?
- И, главный вопрос, какой из способов (а может какой-то другой?) является самым правильным и соответствует всем конвенциям и философии Rails?

Comment: Боюсь, что тут нет ответа про "самый правильный". Первый вариант меня совершенно не устраивает по причине возможности подмены параметра `aasm_state` и в подобных ситуациях я иду по второму варианту. Не вижу ничего страшного в нарушении стандартного CRUD в контроллере. Нет такой конвенции в рельсах "в контроллере должны быть только CRUD экшны"

Comment: На мой взгляд, идея "на каждое состояние 1 мелкий экшен c одной строчкой" - не очень рациональная идея с точки зрения читаемости кода контроллеров (и дело не в CRUD экшенах) и роутов. Сейчас вам требуется только сделать `@order.complete`, потом вы захотите `@order.cancel` и что? Будете опять добавлять новый экшн и новый роут?

Я бы взял первый вариант, но обязательно надо дополнить текущую его версию проверкой на поле state. В таком случае, при добавлении нового state, вам бы пришлось всего лишь подкорректировать код его проверки и все.